# Choices for a Decimal field

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=8)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label=_("Title"), required=False)
    price = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], label=_("Price"))

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        exclude = ('some_fields',)

    def __init__(self, min_price = 10, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        price_field = self.fields['price']
        price_field.choices = (
            (i, i) for i in xrange(min_price, 200, 5))
```

This throws an error because the value for price upon form post is a string, it is not saved on the `Decimal` field in the model.

Typecasting for generators does not work here. What would be the solution to it?

Comment: I believe this is supposed to be a `PriceList` model and FK or `validate_price` method. Not "choices".

Comment: you could try to use TypedChoiceFields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.TypedChoiceField